# Unity resolving unmapped types with null

Tags: unity-container

If I don't have the concrete class mapped to the interface, when Unity tries to resolve the type it gives me this error: "*The current type, IFoo, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?*".

However, for **testing purposes**, I'd like Unity to pass null to the interfaces that aren't mapped yet to concrete types.

Any suggestion to make this as the default behavior to "resolve" unmapped interfaces?

Thanks

Comment: Why not write a wrapper that catches the exception and returns null instead?

Comment: This solution can help it, @Pete, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could let Unity pass null to my dependencies using the OptionalParameter while configuring the constructor injection.

```
container.RegisterType<IObject, MyObject>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new OptionalParameter<IFoo>()
    )
);
```